# Can I use a primer on drywall before taping and texturing, and does it need to be oil based?

Tags: drywall, primer, texture, mudding, taping

We are remodeling and have exposed original drywall that was paneled over.  The drywall  has not been taped or textured, but eventually will be during the remodel.  I don't know if it's because it was covered by the paneling for 45 years, or if it's off-gassing something, but the smell is making me ill.  I've had it tested for asbestos, and it's fine. I feel like priming over it will help to alleviate whatever I'm smelling, because it's going to be awhile before it gets finished.

My contractor said to use an oil based primer to ensure that the future tape, mud and texture will adhere properly.  I see there's also PVA and water based drywall primers available.  I don't really want to deal with oil based primer, but am unsure of the type of primer to use that will allow the future tape and texture to "stick."  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Drywall should not be off gassing enough to make you feel ill.  Instead of trying to cover it, might be better to find the source of the smell.  Might be something behind the drywall that should be removed.  Would tape and mud first, then paint/prime, why repeat one job two times.

Comment: Drywall doesn't really "off-gas"... and after 45 years it's surely not off-gassing anything.  Asbestos doesn't smell either. If you're sensitive to smells, oil-based primer might bother you as well. Can you describe the smell? What other work is being done besides removing paneling? Do you have the option of leaving a window open for a few days?

Comment: The drywall smells musty.  We also have a lot of dust from demolition, so I know that's not helping.  But I can smell the drywall whenever I get within a few feet of it.  Should I try washing it down instead of priming?  Or would that ruin the paper?

Comment: Musty sometimes comes from moisture/dampest.  Would remove a section of drywall where the smell is the worst and check inside the walls.  Are the walls internal or external(on outside wall)?  Might have a small roof or plumbing leak or just high humidly.  Any sections of drywall that look like having a stain?

Comment: No damp, no stains, all interior and all of it smells--not just a section.  The house was built in 1977 and the builder put up the drywall sheets, then paneled directly over it before taping, etc.  So I think it's just musty from being covered for so many years.

Comment: There was at one point some foreign drywall (made in China, IIRC) that had a fishy smell. It all had to be removed. You cannot seal in that sort of smell AFIK. There are primers which can seal in odors from smoke after a fire, but you should consider removing this drywall and seeing if this abolishes the odor.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your input.  However, my original question still has not been answered.  If I do decide to put a primer on, what do I need to use to ensure that the tape, mud and wall texture will stick?  Thanks!